# Passing a class to the SOAP web service as parameter in Java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, parameter-passing

Hi I am wanting to pass a class as parameter to the Web service. 
This is my web service code:

```
<xs:complexType name="RegisterStudent">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="student" type="tns:student" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="user" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

This my my calling function:

```
public static String registerStudentClass(String user) {
soapAction="http://auth.ws.df.com/RegisterStudent";
methodName="RegisterStudent";
String resTxt = null;

Student student= new Student();
student.setAge(22);
student.setName("Jerry");

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, methodName);
request.addProperty("student", student);//Student class added here
request.addProperty("user", user);//User name, passed as string

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
System.out.println("androidHttpTransport envelope");

    try{
        androidHttpTransport.call(soapAction, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        resTxt = response.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        resTxt = "Error occured\n"+e;
    }

    return resTxt;
```

}

This is my Student class:

```
Public Class Student implements Serializable{
  private int age;
  private String name;
  public Student(){}
  public Student(int age, String name){
    this.age = age;
    this.name = name;
  }
  //setter and getter methods come here.
  //...
}
```

After I run this, I get this error: 
'Cannot serialize: Student@4329d250'.Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `Student` marked with `Serializable`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out how to go about doing this:
Firstly, make class serializable

```
Public Class Student implements KvmSerializable{

private int age;
private String name;

public Student(){}

public Student(int age, String name){
   this.age = age;
   this.name = name;
  }
  //setter and getter methods come here.
  //...

  public Object getProperty(int arg0) {
      switch(arg0){
      case 0: 
          return getAge();
      case 1:
          return getName();
      }
      return null;
  }

  public int getPropertyCount() {
      return 2;
  }

  public void setProperty(int index, Object value) {
      switch(index){
      case 0 :
         age = value.toString();
         break;
      case 1 :
         name = value.toString();
         break;
      default:
         break;
      }
  }
}
```

And WebService method looks like this:

```
public static String registerStudentClass(Student stud) {
  soapAction="http://auth.ws.df.com/RegisterStudent";
  methodName="RegisterStudent";
  String resTxt = null;

  //new change
  PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
  pi.setName("stud");
  pi.setValue(stud);
  pi.setType(stud.getClass());

  SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, methodName);
  request.addProperty(pi);

  SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
  SoapEnvelope.VER11);
  envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);//new change
  envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "Student", new Student().getClass());
  HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
  System.out.println("androidHttpTransport envelope");

  try{
      androidHttpTransport.call(soapAction, envelope);
      SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
      resTxt = response.toString();
   }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
      resTxt = "Error occured\n"+e;
  }

  return resTxt;
}
```

I am assuming the response is a text, eg 1 - successfully registered
2 - registration failed etc